# matplotlib can't show marker on the plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I need to show the marker on the line.

However, this code can ONLY display the line, markers are not shown.

The info of dataframe `t_ma`:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 7844279 entries, (2014-07-01 00:00:00, 0 days 09:15:00.500000) to (2015-06-30 00:00:00, 0 days 15:14:59.800000)
Data columns (total 1 columns):
ask    float64
dtypes: float64(1)
memory usage: 106.0+ MB
```

The code to draw the plot:

```
t_ma = pd.rolling_mean(ticker[['ask']],60)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 15), dpi=300)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
t_ma.ix[dt]['ask'].plot(ax=ax1, color='r')
ax1.plot(t_ma.ix[dt]['ask'].index,t_ma.ix[dt]['ask'].values,'^', markersize=10, color='b')
fig.show()
```

Comment: A dataframe snippet please.

Answer (score 2):

Use `marker = valid markerstyle` as the `plot` parameters.

Thus, in your case:

```
ax1.plot(t_ma.ix[dt]['ask'].index,
         t_ma.ix[dt]['ask'].values, 
         marker='^', 
         markersize=10, 
         color='b')
```

There are more additional parameters of `marker`, you can see a valid marker setup below:

```
plot(x, y, color='green', linestyle='dashed', 
     marker='o',
     markerfacecolor='blue', 
     markersize=12)
```

For more options see [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot).